Enforce a Substitution Constraint on a Roster Generation Model in Pyomo
I am trying to develop a Pyomo model that builds an optimal roster for a recreational soccer team. There are 7 positions, R, that need to be filled, and on any given game day, there can be as many as 11 players, P, to fill those positions. Every player has a rating for every position stored in a table. I have successfully implemented the simple problem of building an optimal roster for a given game enforcing some of the constraints below.
There are several constraints or rules that I am trying to enforce:

Every roster position must be filled for each time segment
Each player can only be used once for each time segment
Every player must play at least half of the game
A time segment is defined as half of one quarter
The goalie position cannot be substituted in the middle of the quarter
A unique player must play goalie each quarter (i.e. no player will be play goalie twice in one game)
Total defensive rating (sum of the two defensive player ratings) for any given time segment must be greater than a specified value

However, there is an additional set of constraints that I am having difficulty formulating and describing in such a way that it is an LP problem.

No player will sit for two consecutive time segments (i.e. every player sitting on the bench at the beginning of the quarter will be substituted halfway through the quarter)
The number of roster position changes shall be exactly P - R for each mid-quarter substitution.

In words, I am trying to have every player on the bench get substituted mid-quarter, but no other positional changes be made.
These latter constraints are where I am having a mental block and hoping for some insights from the community.
The rating data are input formatted as such, and then unstacked into a set of tuples and a dictionary to index their ratings by position.

{('Amos', 'CenterMidfield', 1),
 ('Amos', 'Goalie', 1),
 ('Amos', 'LeftDefender', 1),
 ('Amos', 'LeftMidfield', 1),
 ('Amos', 'RightDefender', 1),
 ('Amos', 'RightMidfield', 1),
 ('Amos', 'Striker', 1),
...
 ('Mark', 'CenterMidfield', 9),
 ('Mark', 'Goalie', 10),
 ('Mark', 'LeftDefender', 10),
 ('Mark', 'LeftMidfield', 8),
 ('Mark', 'RightDefender', 10),
 ('Mark', 'RightMidfield', 8),
 ('Mark', 'Striker', 10)}
}

With each quarter and half quarter indexed as (quarter, quarter_half):
{(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2), (3, 1), (3, 2), (4, 1), (4, 2)}

The decision variables are then (truncated for convenience):
match_allowable_assignments_set:

{(1, 1, 'Amos', 'CenterMidfield'),
 (1, 1, 'Amos', 'Goalie'),
 (1, 1, 'Amos', 'LeftDefender'),
 (1, 1, 'Amos', 'LeftMidfield'),
 (1, 1, 'Amos', 'RightDefender'),
 (1, 1, 'Amos', 'RightMidfield'),
 (1, 1, 'Amos', 'Striker'),
...
 (1, 2, 'Ben', 'CenterMidfield'),
 (1, 2, 'Ben', 'Goalie'),
 (1, 2, 'Ben', 'LeftDefender'),
 (1, 2, 'Ben', 'LeftMidfield'),
 (1, 2, 'Ben', 'RightDefender'),
 (1, 2, 'Ben', 'RightMidfield'),
 (1, 2, 'Ben', 'Striker'),
 ...
 (4, 2, 'Lucas', 'CenterMidfield'),
 (4, 2, 'Lucas', 'Goalie'),
 (4, 2, 'Lucas', 'LeftDefender'),
 (4, 2, 'Lucas', 'LeftMidfield'),
 (4, 2, 'Lucas', 'RightDefender'),
 (4, 2, 'Lucas', 'RightMidfield'),
 (4, 2, 'Lucas', 'Striker'),
 (4, 2, 'Mark', 'CenterMidfield'),
 (4, 2, 'Mark', 'Goalie'),
 (4, 2, 'Mark', 'LeftDefender'),
 (4, 2, 'Mark', 'LeftMidfield'),
 (4, 2, 'Mark', 'RightDefender'),
 (4, 2, 'Mark', 'RightMidfield'),
 (4, 2, 'Mark', 'Striker')}

And for completeness, the model is instantiated with this objective function (I have omitted the constraint code for conciseness):
model = pyo.ConcreteModel()
model.x = pyo.Var(match_allowable_assignments_set, within=pyo.Binary ,initialize=1)

model.obj = pyo.Objective(
    expr = sum(player_rating_dict[player][pos]*model.x[(quarter,quarter_half,player,pos)] for (quarter,quarter_half,player,pos) in match_allowable_assignments_set ), 
    sense = pyo.maximize )


I think you are looking to do something like this:
∑(pos) play[t, player, pos] >= 1 - ∑(pos) play[t-1, player, pos]

for all t > t.first() t ∈ time periods
for all player ∈ players
Which basically enforces that each player must play in some position in each period if they did not play in any position in the last period
=======
For the "continuity" constraint in your comment, I think you should be tinkering with something like the below, which should enforce the requirement that the only way to play a specific position is to have played it last time period or not played any position, so you can do something like...
for each player, for each position, for each t: t>t_0:

play[t, player, pos] <= play[t-1, player, pos] + 1 - ∑(pos) play[t-1, player, pos]

Make a truth table and check it.

Thank you for the reply! I was hoping that you personally would respond as I have found many of your answers to others' questions very helpful and insightful! This did help me get past the block on the required substitution. I am still struggling with enforcing only substitutions and not moving a player that is currently on the field to a different position. But I am going to keep working it. I also plan to update the question with the solution described.

@LazyCoder1982 see the updates.  your "continuity" issue should look pretty similar, but needs to be evaluated for each player, position, time slot.  So this will generate a lot of constraints, but that's fine
